# Dropdown must disappear on clicking on sides or escape button

Tags: javascript, html, angular, twitter-bootstrap

I have created one input and, in this input, when anyone search in it, auto suggest product list will be shown. But when anyone click anywhere on the webpage, this dropdown remains as it is. So I need to modify the code so that, when anyone clicks on webpage, the dropdown should disappear.

```
  <div style="position: relative; flex: 1 1 auto; width: 1%; min-width: 0; margin-bottom: 0;">
          <input type="text" class="form-control border-radius-none h-auto" placeholder="Search for All Products"
            aria-label="Search" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" name="searchInput" #searchbar
            (keyup)="fetchSeries($event)" [(ngModel)]="searchInput">
          <ul style="position:absolute;z-index:1;
          background: white;color: black;
          padding:0px 15px;max-height:70vh;overflow-y: scroll; width: 100%;" 
            class="list-unstyled itemsearch">
            <li *ngFor="let show of searchResult" class="py-2 border-top border-secondary">
              <div class="row align-items-center">
                <div class="col-md-2 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center"
                  style="width: 100px; height: 50px;">
                  <img [src]="API_BASE_URL + show.imgPaths[0]" class="img-fluid d-inline-block mx-auto"
                    style="max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%;" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 py-2">
                  <h4 class="text-dark mb-0">{{show.productName}}</h4>
                  <h5 class="text-secondary mb-0">{{show.manufacturer}}</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 d-flex flex-column align-items-end">
                  <div class="text-center">
                    <h4 class="text-dark mb-0">Rs.{{show.finalPrice}}/-</h4>
                    <app-addtocart [id]="show._id"></app-addtocart>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try 'display: none' to the list, adding a click listener to body.

```
<script>
    document.body.addEventListener('click', () => {
      document.querySelector("ul.list-unstyled.itemsearch").style.display = 'none';
    });
</script>
```

Comment: In Angular, could be a way create a class called something like "invisible" with  the param display: none. Then, you can add or remove this class to the element.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by listening document click event

1. Add ElementRef dependency in constructor

   constructor(private eRef: ElementRef) {}
2. Listen document's click event

   @HostListener('document:click', ['$event'])
   clickout(event) {
   if(!this.eRef.nativeElement.contains(event.target)) {
   //Here add your code
   }
   }

Comment: not understood this. please explain with respect to above example.

Comment: You can listen to dom event by host listener in angular. So when ever a click on document  happen other than on your component, it will hit inside the if condition